# A lot of app icon in AVD

Tags: android

Hi I have an android application and it works fine in AVD. But I realized something, there are 6 icon in the menu of virtual device. When I uninstall the app with one of these icons, all icons remove. And each icon opens Main activity. There are 6 icon and I have 6 activity in my app. I am working in Android Studio.
How can I set only one application icon in device menu as normally it should be?
Thanks everyone.

I add a picture of avd menu with a lot of icons

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand anything, and I highly doubt anyone will

Comment: @AbAppletic  I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have these following codes in inside all the activities in manifest file, just keep it in main activity and remove from all others.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This lines will create a launcher icon for each activity.

Comment: Yes it works fine, other icons removed there is just one. Thank you very much @Raviraj Subramanian

Answer (score 0):

You can add external icon in your **manifest.xml** like

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<applicaton>
```

Comment: Yes,  then you can change the icon by giving path of that  icon in drawable folder or mipmap etc.